# WPF Data gird row selection change event from selection change event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'm looking for a workaround to an issue I've noticed in a project that I'm working on.  I have a datagrid bound to a list of a class I've created.  Whenever a user types in a stock symbol in this datagrid I have the roweditending event set to pull in some information to populate the other fields in the datagrid.

This generally works fine, however I've noticed that the event doesn't fire in some instances.  I'm going to try to explain this the best I can... upon data entry if I enter information into a cell and then click another row on the datagrid - focus doesn't shift to the new row but shifts to the row containing the cell I was just entering data into from that cell, then if I select another row or input element the row edit ending event doesn't appear to fire and as such my code to populate the rest of the row doesn't execute.

Everything else is fine, and it's a pretty subtle issue, only one path of input to make it happen, but I was wondering if anyone had run into this or found a work-around?

I've been looking at the selection change event, but I need to be able to grab the row that was selected.  In the row edit ending event I use

```
Dim NewTrade As Trade = e.Row.DataContext
```

to get the instance of my class that the row represents and to add the additional fields.

I'm not sure I see a way to get the row and it's datacontext for the row I just shifted from using the SelectionChangedEventArgs.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: code + XAML + Explain your issue better

Comment: forget events. WPF is not winforms. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: @HighCore I'll look into it, but I've had consistent issues with getting a list of a class to bind to a datagrid properly.  I can get anything else, but not that.  For what it's worth, I think I have it working with the selected item change event.

Comment: @eranotzap I'm not sure what I can provide of the code that will be meaningful - what I'm trying to describe is a particular sequence of input events, shifts in focus, that does not fire the row edit ending as expected.  It works better than 99 percent of the time, it's just a pesky bug, but I think I have it managed by switching to the SelectionChanged event.